# Google Analytics API: page visits from search engines

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

How can I get the number of visits on each page from search engines for some period from Google Analytics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems simple tricks.  [This one Help you to set up per-page Visits](http://www.seomoz.org/blog/11-google-analytics-tricks-to-use-for-your-website)